# npm init doesn't get all packages in node_modules folder

Tags: npm, npm-init

I have a project with a **node_modules** folder. Something unexpected happened and i had to delete my package.json and package-lock.json files. 
Now i need to get my project's packages and dependencies etc.. into a new package.json file.
Unfortunately, running **npm init** doesn't get all packages that are in the node_modules directory. 
For example, react and react-dom are installed and present in node_modules but don't get included in the generated package.json file by npm init; alongside other packages. 
What can i do to make all my packages appear in package.json and also if possible in package-lock.json ?

Comment: I don't think git has anything to do with Node, what do you mean exactly? In any case, fFor good or bad, you can get stuff installed into `node_modules` and not added to package.json, that's how npm was designed.

Comment: @Alvaro Gonzalez Mistake, I meant npm init. My bad

Comment: Then I think you're using npm incorrectly. You don't generate "package.json" from "node_modules", it's the other way round.

Comment: try `npm install`